# Can "boost::algorithm::trim" be used for a leading or a trailing space in general instead of using the left, right versions of it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, std

I am not sure about the string that I want to trim the leading or trailing spaces. It can either have a leading space or a trailing space or both or none. Can I use the "boost::algorithm::trim" algorthm to do so. Specifically, will this algorithm still work if the string doesn't have a leading or a trailing space?

Comment: Yes this will work. If you look at the implementation `trim` will unconditionally call `trim_right` followed by a `trim_left`. So if your string does not contain any trailing spaces it will do nothing with it.

Comment: What would you expect trim to do in case there is no space ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust As I told, I am not sure about the string that can come as input. It can have spaces or it may not have.

Comment: What would you expect trim to do in case there is no space ?